# Guardar diccionario en archivo JSON

Tags: python, json

Necesito guardar un diccionario en un fichero JSON. Inicialmente, este fichero no existe y se crea con la primera iteración.

Primera iteración: se crea JSON y se inserta el primer diccionario.

```
{
  "dict1" : dict
}
```

Segunda iteración: se abre el fichero JSON y se añade otro diccionario.

```
{ 

"dict1" : dict1,

"dict2" : dict2

}
```

```
with open("/ruta/file.json"),'r+') as outfile:
data = json.load(outfile)
data.update(full_dict)
json.dump(data, outfile, indent=4)
```

El error es el siguiente:

> raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Se crea el JSON pero vacío.

Comment: Buen día, has publicado tu pregunta en el sitio de Stack Overflow en español, la pregunta está en un idioma que no es el oficial en este sitio y por lo tanto puede ser cerrada o votada negativamente. Te recomiendo que leas la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Puedes traducir tu pregunta o publicarla en el sitio de Stack Overflow en inglés.

Comment: Por favor, muestra un [repro] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento.